# NSJSONSerialization Json Nested Sub

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, nsjsonserialization

Im trying to get deep into a nested JSon Array, i have successfully done it for the level above but I cant work out how to get any deeper.

I need to log the image @url I have attached a screen show to show where i need it to go.

Thanks :)

[image: json]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.storageroomapp.com/accounts/511a4f810f66026b640007b8/collections/511a51580f66023bff000ce9/entries.json?auth_token=Zty6nKsFyqpy7Yp5DP1L&preview_api=1"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

    NSDictionary *arrayDictionary = dictionary[@"array"];

    news = arrayDictionary[@"resources"];

    [tableView reloadData];
}





-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The data could not be downloaded - please make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wi-FI" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}


-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return  1;
}


-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [news count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *newsItem = news[[indexPath row]];


    NSString *title = newsItem[@"title"];
    NSString *date = newsItem[@"date"];
    NSString *thumb = newsItem[@"tablethumb"];




    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

        [[cell textLabel] setText:title];
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:date];





        if((NSNull *)thumb == [NSNull null]){
            NSLog(@"no image");
        } else{
            NSLog(@ "image = %@", thumb);

        }


    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For traversing nested objects you could use `valueForKeyPath` method and use the dot syntax to drill down the hieararchy.

Something like this would fetch the `url` value from your `newsItem` dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *newsItem = news[[indexPath row]];
NSString *thumbUrl = [newsItem valueForKeyPath:@"tablethumb.url"];
```

PS. If you really have the properties prefixed by `@` then you might get into trouble by using `valueForKeyPath` since `@` [is a special token used as an operator](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/). In this case you could do something like this instead:

```
NSDictionary *newsItem = news[[indexPath row]];
id tablethumb = [newsItem objectForKey:@"tablethumb"];
NSString *thumbUrl = @"";
// Check if not null and access the @url
if (tablethumb != [NSNull null])
  thumbUrl = tablethumb[@"@url"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response I tried the code above and my console said. image = (null), i then tried @"tablethumb.@url" and got a error on the last log of NSUnkownKeyException.

Comment: Yes just realized that you had actual `@` as prefixes. See my edited answer

Comment: @BrentFrench Also note that in your code you're treating `tablethumb` as a string while in your json its a dictionary...

Comment: What do you mean by that? sorry

Comment: I mean that you do: `NSString *thumb = newsItem[@"tablethumb"];` but `tablethumb` is actually a dictionary, not a string.

Comment: oh right, ok when i tried above i get the error v2013-02-22 11:50:49.101 Big Wave App[9488:c07] -[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14fc678

Answer (score 0):

Try to access value from dictionary like this,

```
NSLog(@"URL: %@",[newsItem objectForKey:@"@url"]);
```

Comment: this wont work as there already is  a url in the top level. thanks anyway